# Move web to recycle bin using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, csom

I have the code below, that deletes all websites below a specific web. It works fine, but deletes the webs permanently. I want it to move the webs to the recycle bin instead. What do I have to change in order to achieve this?

```
void DeleteWebs() {
  SharePointOnlineCredentials sharepointOnlineCredentials = 
    new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", ToSecureString("pwd"));

  var context = new ClientContext("https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite1");
  context.Credentials = sharepointOnlineCredentials;
  var webs = context.Web.Webs;

  context.Load(webs);
  context.ExecuteQuery();

  foreach (var web in webs) {
    web.DeleteObject(); // Deletes the web permanently
    context.ExecuteQuery();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems currently not possible. The Recycle method is not available via CSOM or REST API. The following items can be recycled (as of REST metadata on my SPO tenant):

- Folder
- File
- AppInstance
- ListItem
- List
- WorkflowTask

Comment: Yep. And [SPWeb.Recycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/Library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.recycle.aspx) is only available in the Server Side Object Model.